# How to make properties apply to all descendants, not only direct children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is required in CSS for properties to be passed on to all children, not just direct children?

```css
.post>img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <img src="http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/06/21/635704919336245232-967016789_Hair.jpg" />
  <!--This works, appropriately sizing the image. However, if I nest the image, the properties
    seem to disappear:-->
  <a href="http://theodysseyonline.com/ui/4-reasons-why-should-totally-have-crush-bernie-sanders/111812">
    <img src="http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/06/21/635704919336245232-967016789_Hair.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
<!--The sizing on the image disappears :( How can I make all img descendants of 
    .post inherit .post>img's properties?-->
```

The second image, which is nested in an `a` tag, does not inherit `.post>img`'s properties.

I assume this is because it is not a direct child. How do I force all `img` descendants of `.post` to inherit `.post>img` propeties?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/numemv08/)

Answer (score 2):

just remove the `>` (*child selector*) that makes this to apply only to direct children.

```css
.post img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <img src="http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/06/21/635704919336245232-967016789_Hair.jpg" />
  <a href="http://theodysseyonline.com/ui/4-reasons-why-should-totally-have-crush-bernie-sanders/111812">
    <img src="http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/06/21/635704919336245232-967016789_Hair.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're using a ***child combinator selector (`>`)***.

```
.post > img { ... }
```

This selector represents a parent / child relationship. In this case, it targets any `img` element that is a child of `.post`.

If you want to select all descendants you would use a ***descendant combinator selector***.

```
.post img { ... }
```

This selector (just whitespace) targets all `img` elements that are descendants of `.post`.

Learn more at W3.org:

- [8.1. Descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)
- [8.2. Child combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)
- [2. Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) (complete list)